# ListView item with clickable checkbox, and container

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

## Problem

I would like to create a ListView that is similiar to the stock gmail app. I have a CheckBox on the left, and two TextView to the right. I am able to select the CheckBox, but not the rest of the layout. I want to select the Checkbox to activate the Contextual Action Bar, but the rest of the raw should start another activity (two different action for the listeners).
My list item looks like this:
[image]

## Question

How can I create a list item, where different areas of the list item triggers different actions?

## Code

List item layout:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:focusable="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/amount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="right" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkbox" />
</merge>
```

The list item itself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hu.gulyasm.fintrac.ui.TransactionItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/list_item_root"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:padding="24dp" />
```

Finnaly my `getView()` method in the adapter, and the `onClickListener`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.checkbox) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Checkbox pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public View newView(Context arg0, Cursor arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    TransactionItem view = (TransactionItem) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, arg2, false);
    view.setOnClickListener(TransactionListFragment.this);
    // View checkBox = view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    // checkBox.setOnClickListener(TransactionListFragment.this);
    bindToExistingView(view, arg1);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this combo on the checkbox:

```
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: No joy. Only the CheckBox can be clicked, but the id of the View received in the callback is the id of the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `onClick` event for your `Button`, `onCheckedChange` for `CheckBox` in `getView`. And remember to disable focus on Clickable item such as `Button` and `CheckBox`. Here are two very detail blog posts from [Cyril Mottier](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/). They explain detail step and how to fix issue. Your problem fixed with custom Button and CheckBox in `Don’t press everything!` part.

```
    package com.cyrilmottier.android.listviewtipsandtricks.widget;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class DontPressWithParentButton extends Button {

    public DontPressWithParentButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public DontPressWithParentButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public DontPressWithParentButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
        if (pressed && getParent() instanceof View && ((View) getParent()).isPressed()) {
            return;
        }
        super.setPressed(pressed);
    }

}
```

[ListView Tips & Tricks #4: Add several clickable areas](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=525)

[ListView Tips & Tricks #5: Enlarged touchable areas](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=574)

Comment: Unfortunately the checkbox still get checked. The other problem with this approach, is that when I have to extend my list items, I might have more touchable/clickable area. With more area, I cannot use different callback methods, as it was used in the article. I think the only way to do that is to handle that inside the view, and notify the fragment/activity via custom callback interface, or to use the id-s of the views. I start to think that the second idea cannot be implemented, and I have to stick with the first one. :S